# Does this sound vulgar or have sexual connotations?

Tags: offensive-language, connotation

I'd like to ask you to help me clarifying if a brand name sounds sexual/vulgar/queer for native English speakers.

It is "I Job You" which is a social job recommendation site. However, we had some feedback about the name that is has some sexual connotation (blow job? hand job?)

How do you see it? Does it ring any sexual bell for the first read? Can it be used on a native English market?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It certainly rang sexual bells in me, but I cannot say whether it will for others. In any case it is an awkward expression that is perhaps best avoided unless you want it to sound so to attract attention.

Answer (score 6):

I would say that most phrases that have an unintuitive use of a word as the verb between *I* and *you* will end up sounding sexual...

Comment: I _upvote_ you.  Yeah, okay.  :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, I don't think it sounds vulgar or sexual.  It does sound strange since (I think) you are using *job* as a verb in the site name.

To offer recommendations for which you didn't ask, if it's a social site, why not *jobspace* or *workhub* or *jobhub* or something like those?

**Edit:**  I consider myself the inverse of prude.  This name may have sexual connotations in general, but for me, I would first have to get past the weirdness of the name, which I can't.  No matter how I feel about that fruity gadget company, the fact that it sounds like it could be spelled *iJob You* or *iJobU* (as in some university that future Genius Bar workers would attend) hits my brain before sexual connotations.

Comment: Well... I job you somehow tries to resemble "I love you". It refers to that you recommend jobs to your friends that you love, so in this term using "job" as a verb is the playfulness of the whole thing. However, I'm glad it doesn't sound vulgar :) Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any relation between loving someone and recommending someone because he is good at something, nor I like the name of the site at all. ICQ had a similar word play but it made much more sense.

Comment: Thanks for trolling, but the question is really not about if it's a good name or not :)